# What is the ' (single quote) operator in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I've got some examples on how to use a government-supplied library file, but the examples are written in MatLab. Our project is in C#.

Could someone tell me what this means?

```
fid = fopen('d:\coilmodel\outlet.txt');
M = fscanf(fid, '%f', [7, inf]);
fclose(fid);
M = M';
```

I understand I am opening a text file and using that to populate a matrix M that is 7 floating points wide, then it closes the file.

What is `M = M';`?

I can duplicate all of this in my C# code except for the last line, and my only hurdle is I do not know what the action is doing.

Is this a transform?

Is the matrix being transposed?

I'd like to get a reference to this action so I can do further research.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is the complex conjugate transpose (or adjoint) of the matrix M, see [here](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html).

#### Note

As Edric specified, `'` it's the CTRANSPOSE, i.e. the “adjoint matrix or (complex) conjugate transpose”, which gives the same result when applied on real matrices, but on complex matrices

> negates the sign of the imaginary part of the complex elements in A

If you need only to

> interchanges the row and column index for each element

then you will use `.'`.

Comment: Yes! That's it! I'll accept your answer in about 3 minutes (SO won't let me answer it yet).

Comment: the transpose of a matrix is a transposed matrix, isn't it? :D ... I think mine is an italianism, since we say `la trasposta` (the transpose) or `la matrice trasposta` (adjective, transposed matrix), and both are the same and sounds like past participle (the first with the implicit noun "matrix") ... Changed it for a better english appearence!

Comment: It's the “complex conjugate transpose operator”, which is the same as `.'` for real matrices. Edric already addressed this, commented by me too, by the way. The linked doc clarifies, in case one needs to know the difference. I tend to use `'` always.

Answer (score 24):

Note that `'` is the `CTRANSPOSE` operator in MATLAB. If you don't want the complex conjugate, use `.'` which is the `TRANSPOSE` method.

Comment: adjoint matrix or (complex) conjugate transpose, for anyone interested in