# Converting a Matlab loop into Python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

I am trying to convert this Matlab code into python

```
function [h,y,e] = f_adap(x,d,h0,mu)

h=h0; P=length(h);
N=length(x);
y=zeros(1,N); e=y;
rP=0:-1:-P+1;

for k=P:N,
xx=x(k+rP);
y(k)=xx*h';
e(k)=d(k)-y(k);
h=h+mu*e(k)*xx;
end
end
```

So far I have converted it into

```
import numpy as np
def f_adap(x,d,h0):
    h = h0
    P =len(h)
    N = len(x)
    y = np.zeros(1,N)
    e = y
    rP = np.arange(0,-P,-1)
    
    for k in range(P,N+1):
        xx = x (k+rP)
```

Firstly I am not sure if my conversion is correct. Secondly, I have no idea what this line in the Matlab code means

```
y(k)=xx*h';
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `h'` calculates a complex conjugate transpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110921/what-is-the-single-quote-operator-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

In the MATLAB code, y(k)=xx*h'; is a matrix multiplication of xx and the complex conjugate transpose of h. MATLAB performs the complex conjugate transpose using '. In Python, the complex conjugate transpose is achieved by using .conj().T on a numpy array. The matrix multiplication is then performed using the @ operator or np.dot() function.

One thing to note is that Python uses 0-based indexing, while MATLAB uses 1-based indexing. Therefore, adjustments are needed to ensure the indices align correctly.

The corrected Python equivalent of your MATLAB function would be:

```py
import numpy as np

def f_adap(x, d, h0, mu):
    h = h0
    P = len(h)
    N = len(x)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    e = np.zeros(N)
    rP = np.arange(0, -P, -1)

    for k in range(P-1, N):  # Adjusting for 0-based indexing in Python
        xx = x[k + rP + 1]  # Adjusting for 0-based indexing in Python
        y[k] = np.dot(xx, h.conj().T)  # Taking complex conjugate transpose before dot product
        e[k] = d[k] - y[k]
        h = h + mu * e[k] * xx
    return h, y, e
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

def f_adap(x, d, h0, mu):
    h = h0
    P = len(h)
    N = len(x)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    e = np.zeros(N)
    rP = np.arange(0, -P, -1)

    for k in range(P, N):
        xx = x[k + rP]
        y[k] = np.dot(xx, h)
        e[k] = d[k] - y[k]
        h = h + mu * e[k] * xx

    return h, y, e
```

Comment: You've stolen @BradyBerg's code and claimed it as your own.

Comment: To be fair Brady Berg posted at 13:52:43Z and Adam Elhefnawy at 13:56:35Z so about 3:50 later and though similar its not exactly the same. It is certainly plausible that Adam Elhefnawy wrote his answer with no knowledge of Brady Bergs answer until after he posted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).